# Git Pull not working in case of folder that was deleted?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-pull

I have pulled a branch from Bitbucket to my local. It contains multiple folders and I deleted one of the folder and commited my changes. Now, if I do a git pull, then shouldn't the deleted folder appear in my local machine again? Its not happening. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't happen because your `HEAD` will be pointing to your local commit. If you want those files, then revert(reset) your local commit and then do a git pull:

1. `git log`
2. Get the hash of latest commit, which has the change for deleted files, say `<Hash id 1>`
3. `git reset <Hash id 1>`
4. `git pull`

Comment: You should understand that `revert` doesn't "revert" in the literal sense. It adds a new commit with a reverse patch that undoes `<Hash id 1>`. If you've deleted something by mistake and committed it, the right way to undo the commit is to use `reset`.

Answer (score 1):

It will not. The remote (on bitbucket) is at commit `n` and your own repository is at `n+1` (your new commit deleting the file). If you pull, git will tell you that your branch is ahead and that there's nothing new to pull.